Storing the dataset on CPUs but training on GPUs with Lightning
I'm having a bit of an issue when the dataloader loads the training and validation sets into the GPU and it runs out of RAM causing the program to terminate. I was recommended to set the device to CPU and only transfer batches one by one to GPU during training. The problem is that the code is written with Lightning and I can't seem to figure out how to override it.
My accelerator is set to GPU since I'm training in them. Does anyone know what needs to be tweaked around with the Trainer to prevent Lightning from dumping everything into the GPUs from the get-go?

I'm sure someone knows, which answers your question, but also shows that the question as written isn't really suited to StackOverflow. Please have a look at How do I ask a good question? Add some code that shows what you're trying to do and be specific about what you need help with.

PL DataModule is designed to only load batches of data to GPU, not throw them all to GPU at once, so it must be your code. If you want other to help, atleast upload the code
